# how to locate the tooltip by scss

Tags: css, angularjs, tooltip

I'm using in my AngularJS project md-tooltip.

I tried to set the position by CSS by this way:

```
<md-tooltip class="tooltip" hide-sm hide-xs show-gt-sm><span>{{item.title}}</span></md-tooltip>
```

and :

```
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    right: 20px;
}
```

It doesn't work. Is it impossible to do it?

Thanks for help.

Comment: You need to check if there is room in the container to position the tooltip 20px from the right.

Answer (score 0):

Is definitely not impossible. Seems is working on 
[Fiddle (example here)](https://jsfiddle.net/xeupdnfq/3/)
just by setting the class.

```
.tooltip {
position: relative;
right: 20px;}
```

I would suggest you to use the props of the tooltip if you can ( [mdTooltip](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdTooltip) ) tough.

If your code is still not working, probably something overwrite it. Or is just not working the way you expect it?